# Formatting and Aligning output of PrintWriter

Tags: java, eclipse, format

How to format the output file using PrintWriter.

Expected Output

```
09/12/2014 11:58:55   |   9999999996   |    Member - validateBp             |   VALIDATING IN REGISTRATION
09/12/2014 11:58:55   |   null         |    LoginServlet - processRequest   |   ACCESSING PAGE
```

Current Output

```
09/12/2014 11:58:55 9999999996  Member - validateBp VALIDATING IN REGISTRATION
09/12/2014 12:11:00 null    LoginServlet - processRequest   ACCESSING PAGE
```

Thanks!

Comment: please show the code that is producing this.

Comment: out.println(date + id + classname.toUpperCase() + functioname.toUpperCase() + details)

Comment: you could try to edit your question and put the code there.

Answer (score 0):

try
using `String.format`

Lets assume all are `String` except for `id` which is an `int`

```
out.println(String.format("%10s|%10d|%10s|%10s|%10s", date, id, classname.toUpperCase() ,functioname.toUpperCase() + details));
```

Comment: **ERROR** `Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:3999)`

Comment: The above is an example.  I do not know what variable types you are using, as I mentioned in my answer.  Judging by the error I would say that id is a String, so change 10d to 10s

Comment: I have changed 10d to 10s. then I still got error: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '10s'
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2432)`

Answer (score 0):

String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss").format(date));

String Sid = Integer.toString(id);

out.println(String.format("%s|%s|%s|%s, formattedDate, Sid, classname.toUpperCase() ,functioname.toUpperCase() + details));

or

out.println(String.format("%10s|%10d|%10s|%10s", date, id, classname.toUpperCase() ,functioname.toUpperCase() + details));

getting 4 parameter.